# Can MySQL use Indexes when there is OR between conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries plus its own `EXPLAIN`'s results:

**One:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM notifications 
WHERE id = 5204 OR seen = 3
```

[image]

Benchmark *(for 10,000 rows)*: 0.861

---

**Two:**

```
SELECT h.* FROM ((SELECT n.* from notifications n WHERE id = 5204) 
                    UNION ALL
                 (SELECT n.* from notifications n WHERE seen = 3)) h
```

[image]

Benchmark *(for 10,000 rows)*: 2.064

---

The result of two queries above is identical. Also I have these two indexes on `notifications` table:

```
notifications(id) -- this is PK
notification(seen)
```

As you know, `OR` usually prevents effective use of indexes, That's why I wrote second query (by `UNION`). But after some tests I figured it out which still using `OR` is much faster that using `UNION`. So I'm confused and I really cannot choose the best option in my case.

Based on some logical and reasonable explanations, using `union` is better, but the result of benchmark says using `OR` is better. May you please help me should I use which approach?

Comment: Why are you using a select (select union select) instead of using the simpler select union select? Also you need a UNION instead of a UNION ALL to avoid duplicates

Comment: while I don't know the answer -- I too find that OR statments can KILL performance on MySQL.  Often I'll change something like select a.* from account a join account b on a.member_number = b.member_number or a.last_name = b.last_name. --> to   select a.* from account a left join account b on a.member_number left join account c on a.last_name = c.last_name where b.account_id is not null or c.account_id is not null;  To get around the terrible performance of OR conditions.  I'm curious to see the real answer.....

Comment: would be nice if you could remove the `SELECT h.* FROM (` `) h ` in your second example and see if it makes a difference

Comment: What @RolandStarke said. From the docs: *Before MySQL 5.7.6, derived tables were always materialized, whereas equivalent view references were sometimes materialized and sometimes merged. This inconsistent treatment of equivalent queries could lead to performance problems: Unnecessary derived table materialization takes time and prevents the optimizer from pushing down conditions to derived tables.*

Comment: @Quassnoi Well I removed that outer `SELECT` statement, but still the result of `OR` is faster than `UNION` ..

Comment: @Stack: `UNION` or `UNION ALL`? `UNION` has to make sure the results are unique, that's why it probably throws in another temporary table. Try adding `id <> 5204` into your `seen` query and see how `UNION ALL` performs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query plan for the `OR` case appears to indicate that `MySQL` is indeed using indexes, so evidently yes, it can do, at least in this case.  That seems entirely reasonable, because there is an index on `seen`, and `id` is the PK.

> Based on some logical and reasonable explanations, using union is better, but the result of benchmark says using OR is better.

If "logical and reasonable explanations" are contradicted by reality, then it is safe to assume that the logic is flawed or the explanations are wrong or inapplicable.  Performance is notoriously difficult to predict; performance testing is essential where speed is important.

> May you please help me should I use which approach?

You should use the one that *tests* faster on input that adequately models that which the program will see in real use.

Note also, however, that your two queries are not semantically equivalent: if the row with `id = 5204` also has `seen = 3` then the `OR` query will return it once, but the `UNION ALL` query will return it twice.  It is pointless to choose between correct code and incorrect code on any basis other than which one is correct.

Comment: I see. Also yes you are right, if the row `id = 5204` has `seen = 3` then results will be different. However I replaced `UNION ALL` with `UNION` and now results are identical. So in total, do you believe I have to go with `OR`, right?

Comment: Here, here. All the theory in the world doesn't matter one iota when your benchmarking produces contradictory results.

Comment: If the `OR` query you presented is the one that produces the correct results, then the `UNION ALL` query is simply wrong.  It is not a genuine alternative.  Happily, the `OR` query appears to have a pretty efficient query plan, and it performs better in your tests as well.  I don't see why there would be any uncertainty about which to choose.

Comment: You know what?! there is a uncertainty because Gordon *(a perfect person in database subjects)* [suggests me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723716/how-to-replace-or-operator-with-union-operator#37723799) to use `UNION` instead of `OR`  ..! Still are you believe I should use `OR` ? `:-)`

Comment: @Stack, Gordon is very knowledgeable, but in the answer you linked he suggests that you ***try*** a `UNION` subquery to see whether it is faster.  He does not assert that the `UNION` *will* be faster.  In effect, he is saying exactly the same thing I have done: rely on performance testing.

Comment: @tadman In fact you are right .. benchmarks are the most important thing ever ..! But that's scares me to avoid of doing what [Gordon said as a suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723716/how-to-replace-or-operator-with-union-operator#37723799). I say to myself when Gordon tells you test it and there is a contradictory in results, maybe I'm testing wrongly ..

Answer (score 5):

`index_merge`, as the name suggests, combines the primary keys of two indexes using the `Sort Merge Join` or `Sort Merge Union` for `AND` and `OR` conditions, appropriately, and then looks up the rest of the values in the table by PK.

For this to work, conditions on both indexes should be so that each index would yield primary keys in order (your conditions are).

You can find the strict definition of the conditions in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html), but in a nutshell, you should filter by all parts of the index with an equality condition, plus possibly `<`, `=`, or `>` on the PK.

If you have an index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, this should be `col1 = :val1 AND col2 = :val2 AND col3 = :val3 [ AND id > :id ]` (the part in the square brackets is not necessary).

The following conditions won't work:

```
col1 = :val1 -- you omit col2 and col3

col1 = :val1 AND col2 = :val2 AND col3 > :val3 -- you can only use equality on key parts
```

As a free side effect, your output is sorted by `id`.

You could achieve the similar results using this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  5204 id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   seen = 3
                AND id <> 5204
        ) q
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.id = q.id
```

, except that in earlier versions of MySQL the derived table would have to be materialized which would definitely make the query performance worse, and your results would not have been ordered by `id` anymore.

In short, if your query allows `index_merge(union)`, go for it.

Comment: Nice explanations ..! upvote. Just may you please tell me when exactly `index_merge` happens? When a part of conditions is PK ?

Comment: +1 .. Just are you sure? I guess this query `. . . WHERE col1 = :val1` would make benefit of this index `(col1, col2, col3)` .. Because `col1` is the first one of that index.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: not in an `index_merge`, it won't. The PK does not come out sorted with this condition.

Comment: @Quassnoi I see. Do you mean just single column index *(not multiple column index)* will be used in `index_merge` ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh: no I don't mean that. I mean that if you have a multiple-column index, you should have equality conditions on all of its parts.

Comment: @Quassnoi Ah got it .. Also as a note, for this index *(col1, col2, col3)*, this query also is fine: `col1 = :one AND col2 = :two AND col3 > :three` ..! Because `>` is in the last one ..

Comment: There you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630123/multiple-column-index-would-also-be-useful-for-single-column#comment62743365_37630228

Comment: @Shafizadeh: no it's not fine. You can only use ranged conditions on the PK for the condition to be eligible for `index_merge`. The link you provided does not cover `index_merge`. The index can be used for range access indeed, it's just that range access won't return tuples in PK order. There is a link to the docs in my answer, please feel free to have a read.

Comment: When exactly *index_merge* happens? Must one side of that be PK or it may happens when there isn't PK in the columns which are on the condition?

Comment: @Stack: when there are two secondary indexes with conditions allowing to fetch the PK from both of them in order. They are then merged using the sort merge join argorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join

Answer (score 4):

The answer is contained in your question. The EXPLAIN output for OR says `Using union(PRIMARY, seen)` - that means that the `index_merge` optimization is being used and the query is actually executed by unioning results from the two indexes.

So MySQL can use index in some cases and it does in this one. But the `index_merge` is not always available or is not used because the statistics of the indexes say it won't be worth it. In those cases OR may be a lot slower than UNION (or not, you need to always check both versions if you are not sure).

In your test you "got lucky" and MySQL did the right optimization for you automatically. It is not always so.

Answer (score 0):

(The Question is quite old, but I feel the need to point out some flaws -- both then and now.)

- The two queries results are not necessarily identical.  The `OR` will avoid any dups; the `UNION ALL` will [potentially] show a row twice (once for `id=5204`, once for `seen=3`.
- Newer versions of MySQL will better optimize the `UNION ALL` by avoiding the need for the temp table to collect the results of each sub-query.  (This optimization has limitations.  `UNION DISTINCT` continues to require a temp table.)  (Notice "Using temporary")
- "Index merge union" happens so rarely, it is hard to predict when it is used.  "Index merge intersect" almost always indicates that a composite index would make the query faster.
- `SELECT *` is part of the slow-down.  It *may* be better to do something like the following.  It fetched ids more efficiently, the reaches back into the table to get the potentially bulky "*".  If there are big columns, it may explain why `UNION` was so much slower.

  ```
    SELECT *
        FROM ( fetch just `id` from the OR or UNION or whatever ) AS x
        JOIN tbl USING (id);
  ```